# Markdown rendering nested scrollbox in question content?

Tags: bug, questions, markdown-rendering

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022064/my-application-does-not-start-i-get-a-firebase-error-with-login) has a scrollbox inside a scrollbox in the content, which seems like it shouldn't be allowed under normal circumstances

It's about halfway down the searchbar, here's a screenshot for context

[image]

For further debugging purposes (maybe this is a browser issue of some sort, but I doubt it):

``````
zack@desktop ~ $ screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       zack@desktop
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.8.0-58-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 11d 5h 10m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2455
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: zsh 5.1.1
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 4480x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   WM: i3
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   GTK Theme: Industrial [GTK2/3]
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   Icon Theme: Arc
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   Font: Sans 10
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    CPU: Intel Core i5-6500 CPU @ 3.6GHz
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     RAM: 5805MiB / 7884MiB
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/
                   ````` +oo+++o\:
                          `oo++.
``````

Screenshots:

Ubuntu 16.04:

Mozilla Firefox developer edition v57.0b3 (64-bit) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22uI1.png)
Chromium Version 62.0.3202.62 (65-bit) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTgCz.png)

Windows 7:

Mozilla Firefox 56 (64-bit) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ges5a.png)
Google Chrome 62 (64-bit) [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMBAL.png)

Comment: Looks like it was caused by the <pre> tag pair. Moving the closing one to the next line fixes it

Comment: should this still be considered a bug to be addressed or just sort of brushed under the rug?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this hasn't been brought up in the past, just haven't looked for it yet

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in Chrome, and have edited out the extra stray `<pre>` tag.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with chromium, I don't have chrome though, to be clear, you're checking [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47022064/3) right? About 1/4th down?

Comment: It was messed up for me on chrome before the edit (and in the linked revision)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on current supported version of Firefox. Developer/Beta versions are not supported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Added screenshots of supported browsers on windows 7 via browserstack